# Align top widget of column to bottom in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to align the top widget from the end. So the bottom portion of the top widget should be aligned.

```
return Container(
  height: 100,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        width: getWidth(),
        height: getHeight(),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: getColor(),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: getIcon(),
        ),
      ),
      Spacer(),
      Text(
        getText(),
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

But I'm getting this:

[image: Result]

I've tried expanded and align widget but doesn't work.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV8bt.png

Comment: Can you point the issue on image and remove others methods like `getWidth`... and include sample data.

Comment: for some reason the default image sharing is not working. Here is another link with a sample line drawn showing how I want to align the items: https://ibb.co/McV8sGQ

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the approach.

Your present approach.

```
Row
  |_ Container
      |_ Column
          | Image
          | Spacer
          | Text
  |_ Container
      |_ Column
          | Image
          | Spacer
          | Text
  |_ Container
      |_ Column
          | Image
          | Spacer
          | Text
  |_ Container
      |_ Column
          | Image
          | Spacer
          | Text
```

Change it to :

```
Column
  |_ Row          In this row use property of crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxixsAlignment.end
     | Image
     | Image
     | Image
     | Image
  |_ Row 
     | Text
     | Text
     | Text
     | Text
```